# the encoding utf8 is not the preferred name

Tags: html, utf-8, w3c-validation, head

The Nu Html Checker is showing me this error:

```
Error: The encoding utf8 is not the preferred name of the character encoding in use. The preferred name is utf-8. (Charmod C024)
```

and my html head is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

So I use UTF-8, why nu html checker is telling me that I use uft8?

Comment: Try "utf-8" (lowercase).  That's what I put on my sites and it works.

Comment: Does the same happen when you use Nu's 'check by text input' feature? It could be that your server is sending a Content-type header with 'utf8' (not utf-8).

Comment: keep saying the same thing.

Comment: oh, text input is correct!

Comment: Talk to the person who's administering your server for you. If that person is you, check any `.htaccess` file you might have. Or just don't bother, it's unlikely that the missing dash will confuse any real browser.

Comment: I had a ini_set('default_charset','utf8'); in my db connection so I chance it and works! thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the server is configured with the "utf8" charset rather than "utf-8".